# Steps required to protect home network from Raspberry PI infected with malware or hacked?

Tags: networking, security, iptables

I'm not to savvy with network security so I hope someone can help me.

My question is reformulated here to be more precise, something that was requested by other members in the previous question. I reformulated it but they deemed it still not precise enough, however my question still remains and I hope someone won't mind helping out instead of arguing if my question is precise or not. Thanks a lot to anyone that would help.

The new question: Without loosing the ability to browse internet, what are the **required steps using UFW/IPtables** (seems precise enough no ?) to ensure that a Raspberry Pi on my network couldn't affect negatively the rest of my home network in the event that it's infected with malware or hacked from someone over the Internet?

Additional details: I'm familiar with the idea that to browse the net you need to send a "message" and get a "response" from sites etc and therefore if you lock everything on the send or receive you can't browse the net more or less. However I'm just trying to do some preventive damage control using UFW/IPTables but I'm clueless as to how they work. My ISP-issued DSL router doesn't offer a VLAN feature unfortunately as I heard it could've been a solution.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How is this different from your previous question.

Comment: I tried to reformulate my previous question to make it more precise but you deemed it not well reformulated and didn't approve the reformulated version. So I tried to reformulate it here, because it is still not answered and I believe I have a right to ask my question. Are you here to help people or be the "question police" ?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of your previous question this is an impossible goal.

Comment: Instead it was not answered, you Steve made the joke of saying I should put the card in a box etc. not useful at all and not constructive at all. MrWhale touched the subject unfortunately without detailing it. Even if he said there are caveats, it's better than nothing, I would love to hear about the steps: "You could definitely use ip tables on the raspberry pi to help with this, if you restrict all but the necessary outgoing traffic from the pi (http, https, dns etc) then that will stop alot of outgoing attack vectors from the raspberry pi if it were to be loaded with malware."

Comment: @MimeticPolyAlloy I disagree that Steve's comment on your original question was nonconstructive; there were valid points in there with the joke. Your question is incredibly broad, and in all honesty there is no way to *to ensure that a Raspberry Pi on my network couldn't affect negatively the rest of my home network in the event that it's infected with malware or hacked from someone over the Internet?*.

Comment: If one device in your network is hacked, you often have to treat the entire network as being compromised. As far as securing the RPi (and the rest of the network itself) there is really no difference between hardening the RPi and a regular linux box. DigitalOcean has a great selection of tutorials, and I highly recommend you start there. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-securing-your-linux-vps

Comment: If you have specific questions about how to harden certain aspects, those questions would be much more answerable in this format. As is, this site is not very conductive to on request tutorials.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Thanks for the digitalocean link that seems pretty useful from what I saw, I have to dig further in it hoping it will work with an ARM architecture like the Pi's. I found the following but I'm not sure it's the same need, is it ? : http://superuser.com/questions/843457/block-traffic-to-lan-but-allow-traffic-to-internet-iptables

Comment: The principals of network security are totally unrelated to the CPU architecture of the host machine. In this topic, there is little to zero difference between the RPi, and a digital ocean droplet.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Ok thanks for your help and this great link !

Comment: @SteveRobillard Apologies for earlier, I checked in more details how the site works and understand better the importance of precise questions, didn't understand at first the site was more a strict Q&A instead of a forum.